# Passing variables from js to php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, variables, post

I have this form

```
<form name="main" id="main" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="value" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter Value</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value" id="value" placeholder="Enter value">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="value" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Result</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="result" id="result" placeholder="result" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="Convert" name="Convert" value="Convert">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the jquery file is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  $('#main').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : "index.php",     //your processing page URL instead of ???
        data: "&example=2",
        success: function(){
          alert("success");
          $("#result").html("Example content");
        }
     });
  });
});
```

I want to display the example content string on the #result field when the form submits. It seems simple but I have tried everything and nothing works. I get no http and console errors and the alert shows "success"

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I don't see anything with id `result` in your markup. You have `id="re"` and `name="result"`

Comment: @u_mulder Sorry I edited. Still not working.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the jquery library is loaded and the response is 200 ok and yes I am running the project on xammp

Comment: I suppose nothing happens because applying `.html()` to an `input` does nothing. For inputs we use `.val()` function, for example.

Comment: @u_mulder But I am applying html to the #result field. Which is a text field.

Comment: It is __input__. What do you expect from applying html markup to `input`?

Comment: @u_mulder It is working partially, when I remove the ajax request it is working with the ajax request it does nothing. Thank you though I will get back to work

Comment: Did you try `$("#result").val("Example content");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a mistake when you are writing `$("#result").html("Example content");` because it is a input not an element holder.
Change your code to

```
$('#result').val("Example Content");
```

Comment: tried this and didnt work. I was frustrated. Turns out it needed to clear cache and then it worked. Thank you